# Using models in third-party extensions

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using a third-party extension in Yii and I'd like to know, if it's possible to use the models in the extension.

The extension create a table on my database and the model has a relation rule to my `user` table. I have added a relation on my `user` model to the extension's model.

When I do a `findAll` query, it throws me an error: `include(ExtensionModel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

How do I use models in third-party extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration#using-yii-in-3rd-party-systems). In the simple case you only need to include this into the 3rd party files:

```
require_once('path/to/yii.php');
Yii::createWebApplication('path/to/config.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful - see code below:

```
require_once('path/to/yii.php');
Yii::createWebApplication('path/to/config.php');
```